# is random salting causing login not to work?

Tags: php, mysqli, salt

I have a situation with my login page, for some strange reason it just does not allow the user to log in, even though I write in the correct username and password in the text fields. It keeps displaying the message that username or password is incorrect. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Lets say the user's details are this:

```
Username: j.lu
Password cricket
```

In the database it stores these details like this:

```
Username      Password

j.lu          21dfc92f24a130b9259aa650378a3170
```

It stores the password like this in the database because I am including salt.

But does anyone see if I have done something wrong in the login page because it does not login a user at all?

Comment: What is your question? I get *my login script doesn't work*. But where have you found that salting and hashing doesn't work? If you do it right, it *does work*.

Comment: Please read this: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I think you already got the point, "passwords are different between the 2 pages as the salt are randomly generated"

Comment: I updated question to make it easier, my question is that are 2 different passwords being sent through between the register and login php script because of random salt, do the passwords need to require the same salt for both pages so the login cud work?

Comment: @subosito That is my theory, I just want to know if this is definetly true or not

Comment: Yeah, seriously, even though you have the "salt" consistent, once you introduce `mt_rand()`, you **have to save that value**, otherwise that value can no longer ever be calculated *consistently*. C'mon, think about it. If it's random each time it's requested, you're not going to be able to *ever* verify it was the same as when it was *originally* submitted.

Comment: @JaredFarrish There's actually a 1 in 3969 (63^2) chance that the salts are the same and the verification would succeed ;) But yeah, Jared is correct, randomly generated salts used upon every verification is the incorrect way to approach this.  You should either store a randomly generated salt upon the user being registered, or use the same salt across all users; the former is more secure though, of course.

Comment: @Vulcan - Yeah, I meant *consistently*.

Comment: Guys, I just realised that when changing the salt code so that now both pages contain the same salt, it still does not allow the user to log in. So I will edit question and show my login code, does anyone see a problem with my login code because I really don't think there is anything wrong coding wise.

Comment: This is hurting my brain. Of *course* we see something wrong. You have to *save* the *entire* salt. You're making it too cute and complicated. KISS. Emphasis on the *stupid*.

Comment: Please, consider [PHP Pass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: @user1626268 above comments explain it all :)

Comment: And why are you still using `md5`? You should be using `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` or another high-cost, high-round compliment that is expensive to reproduce. `md5` does not fit that requirement.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Im learning how to salt, I will update on the salt later on, just need the login to work

Comment: But your (actual) salt is probably the problem. You're randomizing *every* login attempt. If you can't see that, and you're clueless why your client logins aren't working, please, try [PHP Pass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I will look at php pass but if you look at my code, I am not randoming the salt anymore, Im just sticking it with the same characters for the salt. It is the same salt code for registration and login

Comment: @JaredFarrish Are you saying save the salt in a new column in the database? So one column for the password as I have it now and one column for the entire salt only?

Comment: I don't support any use of `md5`, so I won't support you current practice (see [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)), but whatever you have, it's insufficient. You really need to consider what is necessary, which is 1. multi-round 2. slow 3. unbroken. MD5 is broken, so abandon it. `crypt()` let's you run several thousand rounds, so you should use it (unless you somehow have an earlier version of PHP that doesn't offer it). If you plan on allowing non-ASCII characters, hopefully you have 5.3.7 or later. Nonetheless, the password and DB value *always* have to be calculable.

Comment: To your latest question, yes, if you use a salt value to randomize a hash value, save that *exact* salt value in a table with the salted hashed value (ie, the password in storage).

Comment: @JaredFarrish My version of php is less than 5.3, will crypt work for versions less than 5.3?

Comment: It will, but you have to be careful not to allow ASCII characters, since `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` *in PHP* is broken in pre 5.3.7 versions and less secure than other measures. Seriously, please look into PHP Pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the salts generated when the user is registered, so you can determine the correct hash when the user tries to log in.

The purpose of the salt is to render rainbow tables ineffective. They don't need to be secret (any more secret than the password hash, at any rate), so store it in the same table.

Comment: Although storing the *instance* salt is right if it's per row, if the salt is the same no matter what, I don't think a column in the database is necessary.

Comment: And I just realized `mt_rand()` is called. What the frigidaire.